# Question about using or in mysql query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I wanted to get some clarification, if using OR in a sql statement on indexes does it use the index or no?

For example if I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM account_orders WHERE accountid = 1 OR accountid = 0
```

I have an index on the accountid field

Will mysql use the index? Or would it be better to use a union? I keep reading that mysql doesnt use an index with an or statement, or perhaps Im reading that incorrectly. Any help/explanation would be helpful. Using mysql 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database **won't** use an index if you use `OR` like you have.

The work around is to rephrase it using `IN`. as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM account_orders WHERE accountid IN (1, 0)
```

Databases **will** use an index (if available) with this syntax

Answer (score 0):

Best to prefix your select statement with EXPLAIN. This will report about the result of the query and if any indices were used.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM account_orders WHERE accountid = 1 OR accountid = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I run that alot, I guess I should of asked as a rule of thumb does mysql always not use indexes in a OR statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat off topic, but you could just do:

```
SELECT * FROM account_orders WHERE accountid IN (0,1)
```

Comment: Cool!  I just thought it was more concise.